# USB Communication API

Tags: c++, c, linux, cross-platform, usb

Is there a decent USB communication API? Preferably cross-platform (Linux if not, I guess)

I don't have a specific use in mind, I just want to learn about using the USB ports for future electronics projects. I realize this is very general, I'll try to refine the question as the answers point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[libusb](http://libusb.wiki.sourceforge.net/) should work for you .. cross platform, user-space USB tools.

Comment: Is it really cross-platform? From what I'm seeing its not actually ready for deployment on windows. There's a separate win32 port of the older versions, hardly what one calls cross platform.

Isn't there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your electronics projects, a USB micro controller might be more what you're looking for.

Here is one of my favorite USB devices that do this sort of thing (servo controls, motor controls, LEDs, analog/digital I/O, etc.)
[phidgets.com](http://www.phidgets.com/)

Cross platform, excellent. For example, setting the position of a servo to halfway I could call to the driver:

```
servo1.setPosition(50);
```

Easy as pie.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, not exactly. I am planning on doing something similar but I have no access to those gadgets in my country so I have to build from scratch. I'll probably end up using PICs and such in a design of my own.

At any rate, its more fun this way =P

So yeah, I want to understand USB data transfer as best as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can try for windows WinUSB( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa476426.aspx )
User mode windows USB driver handling - starting from Vista ? (yuck) I have never used it, and it will not work on linux :P Why want you crossplatfomr in first place? 
For libusb for windows, I am not sure if it supports all types of transfers. (depends on version) For device operatons you could use AVRUSB ( http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html ) You need only avr processor and some realy simple extra hardvare.